# Использование булева из структуры

Tags: c#

Можно ли один использовать такой подход в каждом методе?

```
public struct Result
{
    public static bool Status;
}
```

Допустим чтобы в каждом методе не создавать отдельные булевые значения типа:

```
public static bool Status;
public static bool Status2;
```

Comment: Выясните смысл ключевого слова `static`.

Comment: 1-ый кусок кода можно использовать много раз?

Comment: можно. Но результат может тебя удивить :)

Comment: @Grundy, Удивить в каком смысле? Хочу понять практично ли использовать такой способ, имею ввиду через структуры.

Comment: Давайте с самого начала, какая связь между структурой и каким-то методом?

Comment: На самом деле, по твоему вопросу непонятно **что** ты собираешься делать со структурой и как к этому относятся указанные функции `DeleteFiles` и `CopyFiles`. Как ты их собираешься вызывать что передавать, что получать и при чем тут указанная структура. Попробуй написать более понятный вопрос, стоит добавить примеры кода что ты имеешь сейчас и что ты хочешь получить используя свою структуру.

Comment: @Grundy, Убрал лишнее чтобы не было лишних вопросов! Только по факту, требуется ли использование булевых значений через структуру? какие эффекты что даёт?

Comment: @ArteS, вы хотите передать `bool` в метод? Или вернуть из него?

Comment: @Андрей, В самом методе использовать `bool`

Comment: Ну в самом методе создайте переменную и используйте

Comment: @Андрей, он хочет объявить структуру и таким образом не объявлять переменные в каждом методе.

Comment: @Grundy, похоже, я понял, что он хочет...

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

1. Объединять в структуры или классы надо только связанные по смыслу вещи.
2. Экономить же таким образом на объявлении переменных не следует.
3. Использование структуры вместо набора переменных отрицательно скажется на производительности.
4. Использование static не позволит нормально использовать методы один из другого.